# What is meaning of first tilde in purrr::map

Tags: r, purrr, tilde

I was looking at this [example](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/) that uses `map`. Here it is:

```
mtcars %>%
  split(.$cyl) %>% # from base R
  map(~ lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .))
```

What is the meaning of the first tilde in `map(~ lm...`? That is, how does R interpret the first tilde? *(I understand that the second tilde indicates a function...)*. Another way of asking is, why doesn't the following work?

```
mtcars %>%
  split(.$cyl) %>% # from base R
  map(lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .))
```

Comment: Have you read the help for ~? Try `help("~")`.

Comment: It describes what `~` is typically used for. That is, to indicate a formula. Does `map` accept only formulas then?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As per the [map help documentation](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html), `map` needs a function but it also accepts a formula, character vector, numeric vector, or list, the latter of which are converted to functions.

The `~` operator in R creates formula. So `~ lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .)` is a formula. Formulas are useful in R because they prevent immediate evaluation of symbols. For example you can define

```
x <- ~f(a+b)
```

without `f`, `a` or `b` being defined anywhere. In this case `~ lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .)` is basically a shortcut for `function(x) {lm(mpg ~ wt, data = x)}` because `map` can change the value of `.` in the formula as needed.

Without the tilde, `lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .)` is just an expression or call in R that's evaluated immediately. The `.` wouldn't be defined at the time that's called and `map` can't convert that into a function.

You can turn these formulas into functions outside of the `map()` with `purrr::as_mapper()` function. For example

```
myfun <- as_mapper(~lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .))
myfun(mtcars)
# Call:
# lm(formula = mpg ~ wt, data = .)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           wt  
#      37.285       -5.344  

myfun
# <lambda>
# function (..., .x = ..1, .y = ..2, . = ..1) 
# lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .)
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "rlang_lambda_function"
```

You can see how the `.` becomes the first parameter that's passed to that function.

Comment: Makes sense why `lm(mpg ~ wt,...` wouldn't work. Thanks!