# joining dataframe to nested dataframes within purrr::map_*

Tags: r, tidyr, purrr

My aim is to join a dataframe to a dataframes held within a nested list-column, eg:

```
data(mtcars)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

mtcars_nest <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column() %>% rename(rowname_1 = rowname) %>% select(-mpg) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% nest()
mtcars_mpg <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column() %>% rename(rowname_2 = rowname) %>% select(rowname_2, mpg)

join_df <- function(df_nest, df_other) {
  df_all <- df_nest %>% inner_join(df_other, by = c("rowname_1" = "rowname_2"))
}

join_df <- mtcars_nest %>%
  mutate(new_mpg = map_df(data, join_df(., mtcars_mpg)))
```

This returns the following error:

```
# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: `by` can't contain join column `rowname_1` which is missing from LHS.
```

So the dataframe `map_*` receives from the nested input isn't offering a column name (ie `rowname_1`) to take part in the join. I can't work out why this is the case. I'm passing the `data` column that contains dataframes from the nested dataframe. 
I want a dataframe output that can be added to a new column in the input nested dataframe, eg

```
| rowname_1 | cyl | disp |...|mpg|
|:----------|:----|:-----|:--|:--|
```

Comment: Missing `library(dplyr);library(tibble)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple things:

- you should use the tilde to functionize (in `purrr`) the function argument to `map*`; and
- I think you should be using `map` instead of `map_df`, and though I cannot find exactly *why* `map_df` doesn't work right, I can get what I think is your desired behavior without it.

Minor point:

- you assign to `df_all` within `join_df()`, and the only reason it is working is because that assignment invisibly returns what you assigned to `df_all`; I suggest you should be explicit: either follow-up with `return(df_all)` or just don't assign it, end with `inner_join(...)`.

Try this:

```
library(tibble) # rownames_to_column
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)  # nest
library(purrr)

join_df <- function(df_nest, df_other) {
  df_all <- inner_join(df_nest, df_other, by = c("rowname_1" = "rowname_2"))
  return(df_all)
}

mtcars_nest %>%
  mutate(new_mpg = map(data, ~ join_df(., mtcars_mpg)))
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#     cyl data               new_mpg           
#   <dbl> <list>             <list>            
# 1    6. <tibble [7 x 10]>  <tibble [7 x 11]> 
# 2    4. <tibble [11 x 10]> <tibble [11 x 11]>
# 3    8. <tibble [14 x 10]> <tibble [14 x 11]>
```

The `new_mpg` is effectively the `data` column with one additional column. Since we know that we have full redundancy, you can always over-write (or remove) `data`:

```
mtcars_nest %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~ join_df(., mtcars_mpg)))
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#     cyl data              
#   <dbl> <list>            
# 1    6. <tibble [7 x 11]> 
# 2    4. <tibble [11 x 11]>
# 3    8. <tibble [14 x 11]>
```

and get your nested and now augmented frames.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans. Good tip about `~`. Hadn't realised the effect of `~` on evaluation. For others, see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/44834671/2802810