# readLines killing R in purrr::map

Tags: r, purrr

I keep losing my session* in the console when trying to perform readLines (from base) with map (from purrr).

*Don't get new line, and R doesn't seem to be running anything

If I input a vector of file paths:

```
paths <- c("a/file.csv", "a/nother_file.csv")
```

And try and get all top lines out with map and readLines, R dies.

```
result <- map(paths, readLines(n = 1))
```

But if I do:

```
result <- map(1:2, function(x) readLines(paths[x], n = 1))
```

It works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks.  

What is the tilde doing here?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834446/what-is-meaning-of-first-tilde-in-purrrmap for explanation of the tilde

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will work:

`result <- map(paths, readLines, n = 1)`

from `?purrr::map

```
Usage
map(.x, .f, ...)
... Additional arguments passed on to .f.
```

Answer (score 6):

The solution has already been posted. Here’s a brief explanation what happens in your case:

To use `purrr::map`, you are supposed to pass it a *function*. But `readLines(n = 1)` isn’t a function, it’s a *function call expression*. This is very different: to give another example, `sum` is a *function*, `sum(1 : 10)` is a function call expression, which evaluates to the integer value 55. But `sum`, on its own, evaluates to … itself: a function, which can be called (and you can’t call `sum(1 : 10)`: it’s just an integer).

When you write `readLine(n = 1)`, that function is invoked immediately when `map` is called — not *by `purrr` on the data*, but rather just as it stands. The same happens if you invoke `readLines(n = 1)` directly, without wrapping it in `map(…)`.

But this isn’t killing the R session. Instead, it’s telling `readLines` to read from the file that is specified as its default. Looking at the documentation of the function, we see:

```
readLines(con = stdin(), n = -1L, ok = TRUE, warn = TRUE,
          encoding = "unknown", skipNul = FALSE)
```

`con = stdin()` — by default, `readLines` is reading from standard input. In an interactive terminal, this blocks until the standard input (that is, the interactive terminal) sends an “end of file” instruction. On most command lines, you can simulate this by pressing the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Inside RStudio, the behaviour may be different.

Comment: Thanks very much.  The difference between a _function_ and a _function call expression_ was what I needed to know.