# Formula inside Mutate and use of ~

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have a data frame df

`df = data.frame(col1 = c(1:5),col2 = c(2:6))`

I want to transform col1 by adding 10 to each value.

I have found several ways to do it for example using the `recode` function

`df %>% mutate(col1 = recode(col1, "1" = "11", "2"="12", "3"="13", "4"="14", "5"="15"))`

or using `mutate(across())` function.
`df %>% mutate(across(col1, ~.x +10)`

So here are my questions :

1. What are the meanings of x and the . for ? I guess it means for every row of col1 take x and add 10 ?
2. What could be an easier way to do this transformation ?

Thank you

Comment: For one column you don't need `across`, you can do `df %>% mutate(col1 = col1 + 10)`

Comment: Thanks ! I was so obsessed with the function that I forgot the basis.

Comment: Here is another link that might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68249625/understanding-the-dplyracross-function/68249687#68249687

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you don't need `across` since it is only for one column.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(col1 = col1 + 10)

#  col1 col2
#1   11    2
#2   12    3
#3   13    4
#4   14    5
#5   15    6
```

Information about `~` and `.` can be found at [What is meaning of first tilde in purrr::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834446/what-is-meaning-of-first-tilde-in-purrrmap) , [In map(), when is it necessary to use a tilde and a period. (~ and .)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56621051/in-map-when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-tilde-and-a-period-and) and [Tilde and dots in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59855095/tilde-and-dots-in-r)