# Fix error in a For Loop used to extract reviews of a product given different urls

Tags: r, for-loop, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract the reviews of a product on Amazon, the urls of the reviews are placed on the same url with different page numbers, running manually this script is working but I need to change manually the number of the page in the url and the name of the tibble and run each time to get a different tibble.

Since it's quite boring for almost 70 pages I was trying to make a for loop to do the same thing the under the loop that I tried to do but it gives me an error

````
MANUAL 
```
library(tidyr)
library(rvest)

url_reviews <- "https://www.amazon.it/Philips-HD9260-90-Airfryer-plastica/product-reviews/B07WTHVQZH/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_paging_btm_next_16?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=16"
doc <- read_html(url_reviews) # Assign results to `doc`

# Review Title
doc %>% 
  html_nodes("[class='a-size-base a-link-normal review-title a-color-base review-title-content a-text-bold']") %>%
  html_text() -> review_title

# Review Text
doc %>% 
  html_nodes("[class='a-size-base review-text review-text-content']") %>%
  html_text() -> review_text

# Number of stars in review
doc %>%
  html_nodes("[data-hook='review-star-rating']") %>%
  html_text() -> review_star

# Return a tibble
page_16<-data.frame(review_title,
                review_text,
                review_star,
                page =16) 


FOR LOOP

``` 
range <- 12:82
    url_max <- paste0("https://www.amazon.it/Philips-HD9260-90-Airfryer-plastica/product-reviews/B07WTHVQZH/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_paging_btm_next_", range ,"?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=",range)
    
    
    for (i in 1:length(url_max)) {
     
      doc <- read_html(url_max[i]) # Assign results to `doc`
      
      # Review Title
      doc %>% 
        html_nodes("[class='a-size-base a-link-normal review-title a-color-base review-title-content a-text-bold']") %>%
        html_text() -> review_title
      
      # Review Text
      doc %>% 
        html_nodes("[class='a-size-base review-text review-text-content']") %>%
        html_text() -> review_text
      
      # Number of stars in review
      doc %>%
        html_nodes("[data-hook='review-star-rating']") %>%
        html_text() -> review_star
      
      
      paste0("page_", range)<-tibble(review_title,
                                              review_text,
                                              review_star,
                                              page = paste0("a", i)) 
                                                                                       
  }
     ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map_df` from `purrr` to use loop.

```
library(rvest)

page_numbers <- 12:82

purrr::map_df(page_numbers, ~{
  url_reviews <- paste0("https://www.amazon.it/Philips-HD9260-90-Airfryer-plastica/product-reviews/B07WTHVQZH/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_paging_btm_next_16?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=", .x)  
  doc <- read_html(url_reviews) # Assign results to `doc`
  
  
  # Review Title
  doc %>% 
    html_nodes("[class='a-size-base a-link-normal review-title a-color-base review-title-content a-text-bold']") %>%
    html_text() -> review_title
  
  # Review Text
  doc %>% 
    html_nodes("[class='a-size-base review-text review-text-content']") %>%
    html_text() -> review_text
  
  # Number of stars in review
  doc %>%
    html_nodes("[data-hook='review-star-rating']") %>%
    html_text() -> review_star
  
  # Return a tibble
  data.frame(review_title,
              review_text,
              review_star,
              page =.x) 
}) -> result

result
```

Comment: Thank you! your correction worked, I just corrected a small typo in the url_reviews (used the .x ) to correct the typo of the page 16 that was left.

May I ask you about the ~ used in the opening part?

Comment: `~` is formula style syntax used as an alternative for anonymous function. These links have more explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56621051/in-map-when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-tilde-and-a-period-and and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834446/what-is-meaning-of-first-tilde-in-purrrmap

Answer (score 1):

Here's another alternative that defines a function and then uses `lapply()` to sequentially run the function.

The following might, however, be helpful for repeating this as necessary for different products. The function accepts two parameters, the first `i` is the page number and the second `product` is the product for which you are gathering reviews. The function constructs the url by pasting the appropriate page number.

While I used `lapply()`, the function below could also be inserted in the `map_df()` function in Ronak's answer (and would likely be faster than binding rows).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

retrieve_reviews <- function(i, product) {

    urlstr <- "https://www.amazon.it/product-reviews/${product}/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_paging_btm_next_${i}?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=${i}"
    url <- str_interp(urlstr, list(product = product, i = i))
    doc <- read_html(url) # Assign results to `doc`
    
    # Review Title
    doc %>% 
        html_nodes("[class='a-size-base a-link-normal review-title a-color-base review-title-content a-text-bold']") %>%
        html_text() -> review_title
    
    # Review Text
    doc %>% 
        html_nodes("[class='a-size-base review-text review-text-content']") %>%
        html_text() -> review_text
    
    # Number of stars in review
    doc %>%
        html_nodes("[data-hook='review-star-rating']") %>%
        html_text() -> review_star
    
    return(tibble(
        title = review_title,
        text = review_text,
        star = review_star,
        page = paste0("a", i)
    ))
}


range <- 12:82
product <- "B07WTHVQZH"
reviews <- lapply(range, retrieve_reviews, product) %>%
    bind_rows()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @mikebader, the urlstr presents the ${product} before the actual ASIN (B07WTHVQZH), given the structure of amazon urls, the correct form could be this?  
urlstr <- "https://www.amazon.it/product-reviews/${product}/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_paging_btm_next_${i}?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=${i}"

Comment: @Andrea, yes you are correct -- I didn't see that structure of the URL. I have updated the answer.