# With which generality can tilde operator be used to build anonymous functions?

Tags: r, anonymous-function, tilde

Inside some functions as `dplyr::mutate_at` or `purrr::map`, it [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834446/what-is-meaning-of-first-tilde-in-purrrmap) that one can use tilde operator `~` to build *anonymous functions*.

For example, one can do as in the linked question: `map(iris, ~length(unique(.)))`

Or also: `mtcars %>% mutate_all(~.*2)`

I tried to imitate this inside `sapply`, to avoid `sapply(list, function(item) {something_with_item})`. I was writing `sapply(list, ~ something_with_.)` but I get an error

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  '~ something_with_.' is not a function, character or symbol
```

A reproducible example:

```
> sapply(names(mtcars),function(item) mean(mtcars[[item]]))
       mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec 
 20.090625   6.187500 230.721875 146.687500   3.596563   3.217250  17.848750 
        vs         am       gear       carb 
  0.437500   0.406250   3.687500   2.812500 
> sapply(names(mtcars),~mean(mtcars[[.]]))
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  '~mean(mtcars[[.]])' is not a function, character or symbol
```

Why? Understanding this syntaxis as a function is just a behaviour of some packages as `dplyr` and `purrr`? Is it understood by base `R` for some special cases?

Thank you!

Comment: Someone else can go in more depth, but essentially the tilde designates a `formula` object, which the `tidyverse` in general have adopted for non-standard evaluation, while the base apply family don't accept, so still expect a `function` to be provided. See this vignette for more details on its implementation in the `tidyverse`: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lazyeval/vignettes/lazyeval.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As caldwellst says above, the tilda `~` is used to create a formula object, which is a bit of unevaluated code that can be used later. Formulae are not the same as functions, and the `purrr` functions work with formulae because they make a call to `rlang::as_function` (via `purrr::as_mapper`) in the background. The `*apply` functions obviously don't do this, though you can imitate this behavior by calling one of the above functions in your own modified `*apply` function (it's better to just use the `map` functions, the following is just to illustrate the point):

```r
# Write function with `as_mapper()`.
fapply <- function(x, func) {
    sapply(x, purrr::as_mapper(func))
}

# Now we can use formulae.
fapply(names(mtcars), ~ mean(mtcars[[.]]))

#### OUTPUT ####

       mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec         vs         am       gear       carb 
 20.090625   6.187500 230.721875 146.687500   3.596563   3.217250  17.848750   0.437500   0.406250   3.687500   2.812500
```

Answer (score 1):

A formula object is not a function and a formula will only be regarded as a function if the called function that the formula is being passed to has been written to interpret formula arguments as functions.  Many of the tidyverse functions are written that way but in general a formula is not by default a function.

### fn$

The gusbfn package does have `fn$` which will allow just about any function which accepts a function argument to accept formulas.  Preface the function call with `fn$` and then formula arguments are interpreted as functions (subject to certain rules).

In terms of the example in the question we can do this which does not require writing a special version of `sapply` to interpret formulas as functions:

```
library(gsubfn)

fn$sapply(names(mtcars), item ~ mean(mtcars[[item]]))
```

giving:

```
       mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec 
 20.090625   6.187500 230.721875 146.687500   3.596563   3.217250  17.848750 
        vs         am       gear       carb 
  0.437500   0.406250   3.687500   2.812500
```

See `?fn` for more information and examples.

### match.funfn

The gsubfn package also has `match.funfn` which is like `match.fun` in base R except it will also interpret formulas as functions.  This lets one write their own functions that accept formula arguments interpreting them as functions.

In terms of the example in the question:

```
library(gsubfn)

sapplyfn <- function(X, FUN, ...) {
  FUN <- match.funfn(FUN)
  sapply(X, FUN, ...)
}

sapplyfn(names(mtcars), item ~ mean(mtcars[[item]]))
```

giving:

```
       mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec 
 20.090625   6.187500 230.721875 146.687500   3.596563   3.217250  17.848750 
        vs         am       gear       carb 
  0.437500   0.406250   3.687500   2.812500
```

### as.function.formula

The gsubfn package also has `as.function.formula` which will convert a formula to a function.  It is used by `fn$` and `match.funfn`.  For example,

```
library(gsubfn)
as.function(item ~ mean(mtcars[[item]]))
```

giving:

```
function (item) 
mean(mtcars[[item]])
```