# Where is the Purrr ~ operator documented?

Tags: r, lambda, purrr

I searched for `??"~"` but this only points me to `rlang::env_bind` (presumably, `%<~%`) and `base::~`. Within RStudio, how can I find Purrr's `~`'s documentation? For example, if I forgot how to use `~` with two inputs, where do I look?

Comment: The tilde operator is not specific for `purrr`, it's part of the language. See the language definition: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html

Comment: @tmfmnk "_~ Tilde, used for model formulae, can be either unary or binary_". Nothing about that suggests anonymous functions.

Comment: This question/answer might be useful to understanding the ~ (but doesn't point to documentation): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834446/what-is-meaning-of-first-tilde-in-purrrmap

Comment: Yes, and it is stated in the documentation of the `map()` functions that the `.f` parameter  is `a function, formula, or vector (not necessarily atomic).`.

Comment: @tmfmnk So there is nothing special about `~` within Purrr, it's just that Purrr's functions have a special way of reading base R's formula objects? And, for example, this is why base R's `Map` will not work when given formulae expressed in `~` form, even when Purrr is loaded and the same call (albeit with the arguments moved) would have worked for `purrr::map`? Great. That's an answer. Feel free to tidy that up and submit it.

Comment: I think that the use of tilde operator in `purrr::map()` is beautifully explained in the thread linked by @aosmith . Then, as far as I'm concerned, `base::Map()` does not accept a formula as its `f` parameter.

Comment: @J.Mini, in response to your *"nothing about that suggests anonymous functions"*, I'll say that nothing in your question suggests anon-funcs, either. Yes, some functions in `purrr` allow special use of the `~` as a fake function, but then again, I believe they do nothing special but use its constructs as already provided by R. Most base-R functions do not support this, it's primarily (solely?) with tidyverse packages.

Comment: If you forget how to use `~` with two inputs, then you need to look at the function that is allowing the `~`-function, not `~` itself. For instance, `purrr::pmap` shows three ways to parameterize it, using `.` (single argument), `.x` and `.y` (if only two), or `..1`, `..2`, `..3`, etc for multi-arg `~`-functions.

Comment: @r2evans Completely fair and correct points, but for what it's worth, I don't think that the documentation for `pmap` shows how to use the `..n` variants.

Comment: Huh? `?pmap`: `.f: A function, formula, or vector ... - For more arguments, use '..1', '..2', '..3' etc`. Perhaps there's a version discrepancy? (Or I'm just missing something else ...)

Comment: @r2evans I was specifically referring to there being no such examples in the example code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a good explanation given AdvanceR (link given in another answer).  There is also a short description (usage example) given in [purrr cheatsheat](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/blob/master/purrr.pdf) first page bottom left.

[image]

The usage of multiple arguments with twiddle `~` may be seen at with documentation of purrr given in its different functions.  e.g. [map](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) see argument description which states that

> .f
> A function, formula, or vector (not necessarily atomic).
> If a function, it is used as is.
> If a formula, e.g. ~ .x + 2, it is converted to a function. There are three ways to refer to the arguments:
> For a single argument function, use .

> For a two argument function, use .x and .y

> For more arguments, use ..1, ..2, ..3 etc

> This syntax allows you to create very compact anonymous functions.

---

Moreover, R in its newest version (4.1.0) has also [started](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/NEWS.R-4.1.0patched.html) similar kind of shorthand notation of functions

> R now provides a shorthand notation for creating functions, e.g. \(x) x + 1 is parsed as function(x) x + 1.

This shorthand notation may also provide useful in functions outside tidyverse, with only differentiation from `twiddle` being that here arguments are not named by default.  But again, this non-default naming may also be proved useful when one invisible function is to be used inside another and `twiddle` style of notation will not work in that case.

Comment: `twiddle` is very different from the new base R anonymous function syntax. For example, `twiddle` does not actually make an anonymous function; purrr's functions merely coerce the formula object to what they can treat as a function.

Comment: @J.Mini, yes you're right and I am aware of this.  May be I was unable to convey this properly.

Answer (score 7):

When you use `~` within the context of `purrr` functions, it will be passed to the [`as_mapper()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/as_mapper.html) function, which in turn passes on to the [`as_function()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/as_function.html) function from `rlang`. These help files have a very basic bit of what is needed to use this. This is further documented in the [Advanced R Book Chapter 9, Section 9.22](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html#purrr-shortcuts), which has a few good examples, and this chapter goes on to continue those ideas.