# In ggplot, how to fill area between two normal curves

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two normal curves and I want to fill the right area between both curves, so left curve is inferior y limit and right  curve is superior y limit. To plot the curves I am using `stat_function()`  so `ggplot` draws the curve without defining an y-column  in `aes()`. I have drawn the fill area between the curve and the X axis, but I need the area between both curves and the trick of emptying the left curve with `NA` doesn't seem to work as I expected.

The code to generate the plot is in a function as I need to plot several different couples of normal curves.

How can I do that?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

graf_normal <- function(Xmedia1, Xdt1, Xmedia2, Xdt2) {

  Xmin1 <- Xmedia1-4*Xdt1
  Xmax1 <- Xmedia1+4*Xdt1

  Xmin2 <- Xmedia2-4*Xdt2
  Xmax2 <- Xmedia2+4*Xdt2

  Ymax1 <- max(dnorm(Xmedia1, Xmedia1, Xdt1))
  Ymax2 <- max(dnorm(Xmedia2, Xmedia2, Xdt2))

  Xmin <- min(Xmin1, Xmin2)
  Xmax <- max(Xmax1, Xmax2)

  ggplot(data.frame(X = c(Xmin, Xmax)), aes(x = X)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "grey", linewidth = 1) +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, 
              args = c(Xmedia1, Xdt1), 
              linewidth = 1, 
              colour = "grey") +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, 
              args = c(Xmedia2, Xdt2), 
              linewidth = 1, 
              colour = "black") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = Xmedia1, y = 0, xend = Xmedia1, yend = Ymax1), 
             linetype = "dashed", 
             linewidth = 0, 
             colour = "grey") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = Xmedia2, y = 0, xend = Xmedia2, yend = Ymax2), 
             linetype = "dashed", 
             linewidth = 0, 
             colour = "black") +
  ####################################################################
  stat_function(fun = dnorm,
            args = c(Xmedia2, Xdt2),
            xlim = c(Xmedia2+1.5*Xdt2,Xmax2),
            geom = "area",
            fill = "red",
            alpha = 0.5) +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm,
              args = c(Xmedia1, Xdt1),
              xlim = c(Xmedia1,Xmax1),
              geom = "area",
              fill = NA,
              alpha = 0.01) +

  ##################################################################

  theme(
    line = element_blank(),
    axis.line.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis. Ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    legend. Position = "none",
    panel. Grid = element_blank(),
    panel. Background = element_rect(fill = "lightgray", colour = NA),
 ) +
 xlim(c(Xmin, Xmax)) 
}

g1 <- graf_normal(250, 7, 253, 7)

g1
```

The plot of both curves I get is this:
[image: Two normal curves]

Thanks,

**EDIT:**
Using @stephan's code and playing with data filtering, I've been able to do this, easier using `geom_ribbon()`:
[image: Shading overlapping zones]

Cool way of differencing overlapping zones!
Complete code:

```
library(ggplot2)

graf_normal <- function(Xmedia1, Xdt1, Xmedia2, Xdt2, n = 1000) {
  x1 <- Xmedia1 + 4 * Xdt1 * seq(-1, 1, length. Out = n)
  x2 <- Xmedia2 + 4 * Xdt2 * seq(-1, 1, length. Out = n)

  dat <- data. Frame(
    x = union(x1, x2)
  )
  dat$y1 <- dnorm(dat$x, Xmedia1, Xdt1)
  dat$y2 <- dnorm(dat$x, Xmedia2, Xdt2)

  Ymax1 <- dnorm(Xmedia1, Xmedia1, Xdt1)
  Ymax2 <- dnorm(Xmedia2, Xmedia2, Xdt2)

  ggplot(dat, aes(x)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "grey", linewidth = 1) +
    geom_ribbon(
      data =  subset(dat, x >= Xmedia2 + 1.5 * Xdt2),
      aes(ymin = y1, ymax = y2),
      fill = "red", alpha = 0.8
    ) +
    geom_ribbon(
      data =  subset(dat, (x <= Xmedia2 + 1.5 * Xdt2) & (y2 > y1)),
      aes(ymin = y1, ymax = y2),
      fill = "red", alpha = 0.2
    ) +
    geom_ribbon(
      data = subset(dat, x <= Xmedia1 - 1.5 * Xdt2),
      aes(ymin = y1, ymax = y2),
      fill = "blue", alpha = 0.8
    ) +
    geom_ribbon(
      data = subset(dat, (x <= Xmedia2 ) & (y1 > y2)),
      aes(ymin = y1, ymax = y2),
      fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2
    ) +
    annotate(
      geom = "segment",
      x = c(Xmedia1, Xmedia2), y = 0,
      xend = c(Xmedia1, Xmedia2), yend = c(Ymax1, Ymax2),
      linetype = "dashed",
      linewidth = 1,
      colour = c("grey", "black")
    ) +
    geom_line(aes(y = y1), linewidth = 1, colour = "grey") +
    geom_line(aes(y = y2), linewidth = 1, colour = "black") +
    theme(
      line = element_blank(),
      axis.line.y = element_blank(),
      axis. Text = element_blank(),
      axis. Ticks = element_blank(),
      axis. Title = element_blank(),
      legend. Position = "none",
      panel. Grid = element_blank(),
      panel. Background = element_rect(fill = "lightgray", colour = NA),
    )
}

graf_normal(250, 7, 253, 7)
```

However, the code doesn't work for all curves, working on it!:

```
graf_normal(250, 7, 253, 3)
```

[image: Bad filling]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option to fill the area between the normal curves would be to use `ggh4x::stat_difference` which however requires to compute the values for the densities manually and drawing via `geom_line` instead of relying on `stat_function()`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)
graf_normal <- function(Xmedia1, Xdt1, Xmedia2, Xdt2, n = 101) {
  x1 <- Xmedia1 + 4 * Xdt1 * seq(-1, 1, length.out = n)
  x2 <- Xmedia2 + 4 * Xdt2 * seq(-1, 1, length.out = n)
  
  dat <- data.frame(
    x = union(x1, x2)
  )
  dat$y1 <- dnorm(dat$x, Xmedia1, Xdt1)
  dat$y2 <- dnorm(dat$x, Xmedia2, Xdt2)

  Ymax1 <- dnorm(Xmedia1, Xmedia1, Xdt1)
  Ymax2 <- dnorm(Xmedia2, Xmedia2, Xdt2)

  ggplot(dat, aes(x)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "grey", linewidth = 1) +
    ggh4x::stat_difference(
      data = ~ subset(.x, x >= Xmedia2 + 1.5 * Xdt2),
      aes(ymin = y1, ymax = y2)
    ) +
    annotate(
      geom = "segment",
      x = c(Xmedia1, Xmedia2), y = 0,
      xend = c(Xmedia1, Xmedia2), yend = c(Ymax1, Ymax2),
      linetype = "dashed",
      linewidth = 1,
      colour = c("grey", "black")
    ) +
    geom_line(aes(y = y1), linewidth = 1, colour = "grey") +
    geom_line(aes(y = y2), linewidth = 1, colour = "black") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c(scales::alpha("red", .5), "transparent")) +
    theme(
      line = element_blank(),
      axis.line.y = element_blank(),
      axis.text = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
      axis.title = element_blank(),
      legend.position = "none",
      panel.grid = element_blank(),
      panel.background = element_rect(fill = "lightgray", colour = NA),
    )
}

graf_normal(250, 7, 253, 7)
```

[image]

**EDIT** Actually `stat_differnce` is not really needed for your case. Was thinking too complicated. As @JuanRiera mentioned in his comment, we could fill the area using a `geom_ribbon`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

graf_normal <- function(Xmedia1, Xdt1, Xmedia2, Xdt2, n = 101) {
  x1 <- Xmedia1 + 4 * Xdt1 * seq(-1, 1, length.out = n)
  x2 <- Xmedia2 + 4 * Xdt2 * seq(-1, 1, length.out = n)

  dat <- data.frame(
    x = union(x1, x2)
  )
  dat$y1 <- dnorm(dat$x, Xmedia1, Xdt1)
  dat$y2 <- dnorm(dat$x, Xmedia2, Xdt2)

  Ymax1 <- dnorm(Xmedia1, Xmedia1, Xdt1)
  Ymax2 <- dnorm(Xmedia2, Xmedia2, Xdt2)

  ggplot(dat, aes(x)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "grey", linewidth = 1) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = y1, ymax = y2),
      data = subset(dat, x >= Xmedia2 + 1.5 * Xdt2),
      fill = "red", alpha = 0.5
    ) +
    annotate(
      geom = "segment",
      x = c(Xmedia1, Xmedia2), y = 0,
      xend = c(Xmedia1, Xmedia2), yend = c(Ymax1, Ymax2),
      linetype = "dashed",
      linewidth = 1,
      colour = c("grey", "black")
    ) +
    geom_line(aes(y = y1), linewidth = 1, colour = "grey") +
    geom_line(aes(y = y2), linewidth = 1, colour = "black") +
    theme(
      line = element_blank(),
      axis.line.y = element_blank(),
      axis.text = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
      axis.title = element_blank(),
      legend.position = "none",
      panel.grid = element_blank(),
      panel.background = element_rect(fill = "lightgray", colour = NA),
    )
}

graf_normal(250, 7, 253, 7)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Stefan, your code adds some nice ideas like the annotation better coded. However the use of another library is not ideal for the environment where I must deploy the solution. I will think about your solution and r2evans.

Comment: Hi Juan. Sure. Feel free to choose whatever approach fits your needs best. And of course could you mix both, i.e. you could replace ggh4x::stat_difference in my code with the `geom_polygon` approach by @r2evans.

Comment: I wanted to edit but I can't after 5 min lol - your code adds MANY nice ideas!

Comment: Stefan, I just checked that `ggh4x::stat_difference(` can be directly  replaced by `geom_ribbon(` and the code works nicely same way

Comment: BTW, could you please explain the use of tilde in `~ subset(.x, x >= Xmedia2 + 1.5 * Xdt2)`? Can't find anything about it

Comment: Haha. Yeah, of course. Was thinking too complicated. For your case we could simply use `geom_ribbon`. `stat_difference` is only needed if we want to fill starting at the intersection point or in case that we want to fill the area between the densities over the whole range of data. Concerning`~ subset(.x, x >= Xmedia2 + 1.5 * Xdt2)`: It subsets the data passed to `ggplot()`. In your case we could simply do `subset(dat, ...)`. But using this notation is handy in case where we do something like `dat %>% filter(...) %>% ggplot(...)`.

Comment: Well, believe it or not, you anticipated my next question: ¿how to fill from intersection? Just by not doing a subset and using the whole dataset `dat`: *voilà*, done! This thing it's being fun :)

Comment: My doubt  it's about tilde notation, with the use of tilde before `~subset` and not with `subset` function - I have never used tilde before a function and It's not clear to me what's it used for. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Juan. You find the `~` notation all over the tidyverse. Basically `~ f(.x)` is the same as `function(.x) f(.x)` just shorter. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67643144/where-is-the-purrr-operator-documented for some references.

Answer (score 3):

One way is using a `geom_polygon` instead of `stat_function`.

Add this to your function, before the `ggplot()`:

```r
  poly <- data.frame(xs = seq(Xmedia2+1.5*Xdt2, Xmax2, length.out = n)) |>
    transform(
      y1 = dnorm(xs, Xmedia1, Xdt1),
      y2 = dnorm(xs, Xmedia2, Xdt2)
    ) |>
    with(data.frame(X = c(xs, rev(xs)), Y = c(y1, rev(y2))))
```

And then replace your both of your second two `stat_function` calls with a single

```r
  geom_polygon(aes(X, Y), data = poly,
               fill = "red", alpha = 0.5) +
```

[image: ggplot2 with ribbon between dnorm curves]

Full source:

```r
graf_normal <- function(Xmedia1, Xdt1, Xmedia2, Xdt2, n = 20) {

  Xmin1 <- Xmedia1-4*Xdt1
  Xmax1 <- Xmedia1+4*Xdt1

  Xmin2 <- Xmedia2-4*Xdt2
  Xmax2 <- Xmedia2+4*Xdt2

  Ymax1 <- max(dnorm(Xmedia1, Xmedia1, Xdt1))
  Ymax2 <- max(dnorm(Xmedia2, Xmedia2, Xdt2))

  Xmin <- min(Xmin1, Xmin2)
  Xmax <- max(Xmax1, Xmax2)

  poly <- data.frame(xs = seq(Xmedia2+1.5*Xdt2, Xmax2, length.out = n)) |>
    transform(
      y1 = dnorm(xs, Xmedia1, Xdt1),
      y2 = dnorm(xs, Xmedia2, Xdt2)
    ) |>
    with(data.frame(X = c(xs, rev(xs)), Y = c(y1, rev(y2))))

  ggplot(data.frame(X = c(Xmin, Xmax)), aes(x = X)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "grey", linewidth = 1) +
  geom_polygon(aes(X, Y), data = poly,
               fill = "red", alpha = 0.5) +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, 
              args = c(Xmedia1, Xdt1), 
              linewidth = 1, 
              colour = "grey") +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, 
              args = c(Xmedia2, Xdt2), 
              linewidth = 1, 
              colour = "black") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = Xmedia1, y = 0, xend = Xmedia1, yend = Ymax1), 
             linetype = "dashed", 
             linewidth = 0, 
             colour = "grey") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = Xmedia2, y = 0, xend = Xmedia2, yend = Ymax2), 
             linetype = "dashed", 
             linewidth = 0, 
             colour = "black") +
  ####################################################################
  # stat_function(fun = dnorm,
  #           args = c(Xmedia2, Xdt2),
  #           xlim = c(Xmedia2+1.5*Xdt2,Xmax2),
  #           geom = "area",
  #           fill = "red",
  #           alpha = 0.5) +
  # stat_function(fun = dnorm,
  #             args = c(Xmedia1, Xdt1),
  #             xlim = c(Xmedia1,Xmax1),
  #             geom = "area",
  #             fill = NA,
  #             alpha = 0.01) +
  ##################################################################
  theme(
    line = element_blank(),
    axis.line.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "none",
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "lightgray", colour = NA),
    ) +
    xlim(c(Xmin, Xmax)) 

}
```

Note: I chose to move the `geom_polygon` to much earlier in the plot-stack so that the `dnorm`-lines would be "on top" of the red area. Whether this is important depends on your context and rendering engine.

Comment: I like in this solution that code is less modified, even if my code is not too efficient, I think it it may be clearer in the context I will use it, with people learning to code. I see from both answers that I need to generate the Y values, and I can't rely on included functions. Not a major problem, in any case. Thanks a lot, r2evans.

Comment: I know of no function that automates "area between two curves" other than perhaps stefan's suggestion for `ggh4x::stat_difference` (I haven't tried it). Glad it works for you!